# Solving a Probability question with only one given percentage

Tags: probability

The question is: what is the probability that at least one of two randomly selected adults snore?
I thought I would need to solve this problem using $P(E \cup F)= P(E)+P(F)-P(E \cap F)$
however, I only have one given.  My given is 36% off all adults
Where do I go from here?

Comment: How are the events $E$ and $F$ related?

Comment: 36% of ALL adults. You're given everything you need.

Comment: If the two adults are selected independently, then each one's snoring is independent of the other's.  So you should be able to say what $P(E\cap F)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You are given that $P(E)=P(F)=0.36$ and the the events are independent.  That should allow you to calculate $P(E\cap F)$ and use your formula.